Intersection of two vector parametric equations of lines
Given
R: (x0, y0) = (1, 2), 
v^ = (3/5, 4/5) (and u^ being perpendicular to v^),
P: (x1, y1) = (2, 15/2),
find point Q which is the intersection between line lp (from P through u^) and line lr (from R through v^).

There are two things I am uncertain about: 1) u^ is perpendicular, thus the slope is inverse, thus I get +- (4/5, 3/5), however should the y or x be negative? This has consequences for the calculation and my lecture slides give varying information.
2) Once I have the two lines lp and lr, they look something like this:
(x0, y0) + t (4/5, -3/5)
and,
(x1, y1) + l (3/5, 4/5)

So I equate the x-components, i.e. x0 ... = x1 ...
I solve for either t or l, let's say I solve for l
Then what should I do, should I put l into the x-components again and solve for t, or should I put it in the y-components and solve for t? Any advice?

Please format your formulas.

First of all, consider the definition of being perpendicular. Given your vector $\mathbf{v}$, a vector $\mathbf{u} = (a, b)^T$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$ if the inner product between the two is zero. Therefore you get that $3a+4b = 0$, hence $\mathbf{u} = (-4,\ 3)^T$.
As for your second question you have two equations in two variables ($t, l$ in your case). You can solve in one variable and substitute in the other equation so you can find one between $l, t$. With that value your problem is solved because you can plug it back into the line equation.
The system should be this one:
$$\begin{cases}1+3l = 2-4t \\
2+4l = \frac{15}{2} + 3t\end{cases}.$$
If you solve it for $t$ you get $t = -\frac{1}{2}$ and plugging it into the corresponding line equation you get $\begin{pmatrix}2\\ \frac{15}{2}\end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}-4\\3\end{pmatrix} = (4,\  6)^T$.

but what if a = 4, and b = -3? wouldn't that be the same, and thus (4, -3)^T be valid?

also, taking one variable to solve, i take 2 - 4t = 0, and solve for t; this gives me 1/2, not -1/2, and is dependent on which sign I give the perpendicular vector components

and as an alternative if you meant 2 - 4t = 15/2 + 3t, then this gives -11/14, which certainly isn't right

After trial and error I got it, you take the entire first equation and solve for l, then you plug l into the entire second equation and get t. Then when you put t into the entire equation you get (4, 6). I see now, thank you. However, I am still not confident on the perpendicular vector question.

@computermarty Remember that you can define any line as a point and a directional vector. I can multiply the vector by any scalar value and still get the same line. Therefore the space generated by $(4, -3)^T$ is the same one generated by $(-4, 3)^T$ and the lines are the same.

In this case you're not equating the $x$ components and the $y$ components. Think about what it means having two lines that intersect in a point.

Right, so (4, -3)^T = (-4, 3)^T, so which component gets the negative sign is arbitrary
